# Circumventing R's `Error in if (nbins > .Machine$integer.max)`

Tags: sql, r, memory, stata

This is a saga which began with the problem of [how to do survey weighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446078/frequency-weighting-in-r-comparing-results-with-stata). Now that I appear to be doing that correctly, I have hit a bit of a wall (see previous post for details on the import process and where the `strata` variable came from):

```
> require(foreign)
> ipums <- read.dta('/path/to/data.dta')
> require(survey)
> ipums.design <- svydesign(id=~serial, strata=~strata, data=ipums, weights=perwt)
Error in if (nbins > .Machine$integer.max) stop("attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In pd * (as.integer(cat) - 1L) : NAs produced by integer overflow
2: In pd * nl : NAs produced by integer overflow
> traceback()
9: tabulate(bin, pd)
8: as.vector(data)
7: array(tabulate(bin, pd), dims, dimnames = dn)
6: table(ids[, 1], strata[, 1])
5: inherits(x, "data.frame")
4: is.data.frame(x)
3: rowSums(table(ids[, 1], strata[, 1]) > 0)
2: svydesign.default(id = ~serial, weights = ~perwt, strata = ~strata, 
       data = ipums)
1: svydesign(id = ~serial, weights = ~perwt, strata = ~strata, data = ipums)
```

This error seems to come from the [`tabulate`](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/base/R/tabulate.R) function, which I hoped would be straightforward enough to circumvent, first by changing `.Machine$integer.max`

```
> .Machine$integer.max <- 2^40
```

and when that didn't work the whole source code of `tabulate`:

```
> tabulate <- function(bin, nbins = max(1L, bin, na.rm=TRUE))
{
    if(!is.numeric(bin) && !is.factor(bin))
    stop("'bin' must be numeric or a factor")
    #if (nbins > .Machine$integer.max)
    if (nbins > 2^40) #replacement line
        stop("attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements")
    .C("R_tabulate",
       as.integer(bin),
       as.integer(length(bin)),
       as.integer(nbins),
       ans = integer(nbins),
       NAOK = TRUE,
       PACKAGE="base")$ans
}
```

Neither circumvented the problem. Apparently this is one reason why the `ff` package was created, but what worries me is the extent to which this is a problem I cannot avoid in `R`. [This post](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/NEWS) seems to indicate that even if I were to use a package that would avoid this problem, I would only be able to access 2^31 elements at a time. My hope was to use `sql` (either `sqlite` or `postgresql`) to get around the memory problems, but I'm afraid I'll spend a while getting that to work, only to run into the same fundamental limit.

Attempting to switch back to `Stata` doesn't solve the problem either. Again see the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446078/frequency-weighting-in-r-comparing-results-with-stata) for how I use `svyset`, but the calculation I would like to run causes `Stata` to hang:

```
svy: mean age, over(strata)
```

Whether throwing more memory at it will solve the problem I don't know. I run `R` on my desktop which has 16 gigs, and I use `Stata` through a Windows server, currently setting memory allocation to 2000MB, but I could theoretically experiment with increasing that.

So in sum:

1. Is this a hard limit in `R`?
2. Would `sql` solve my `R` problems?
3. If I split it up into many separate files would that fix it (a lot of work...)?
4. Would throwing a lot of memory at `Stata` do it?
5. Am I seriously barking up the wrong tree somehow?

Comment: use `traceback()` after the error and figure out why svydesign is trying to tabulate such a large table -- maybe you've specified an incorrect formula, or have represented data incorrectly (e.g., a long 'id' string as `numeric` rather than `factor`).

Comment: Ah, my id and strata variables are indeed integers rather than factors. Will try that and let you know. Also added the `traceback()` above.

Comment: I've converted both `serial` (passed into `id`) and `strata` (passed eponymously) to factors from integers and get the same error (it seems to raise the error quicker though).

Comment: It seems they were in fact floats initially that I need to convert them to integers. I still can't do the calculation on the whole dataset, but I can for subsets. Leaving as a factor reproduces the same error irrespective of the length of the subset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both @Gavin and @Martin deserve credit for this answer, or at least leading me in the right direction. I'm mostly answering it separately to make it easier to read.

In the order I asked:

1. Yes 2^31 is a hard limit in `R`, though it seems to matter what type it is (which is a bit strange given it is the *length* of the vector, rather than the amount of memory (which I have plenty of) which is the stated problem. Do **not** convert `strata` or `id` variables to `factors`, that will just fix their length and nullify the effects of subsetting (which is the way to get around this problem).
2. `sql` could probably help, provided I learn how to use it correctly. I did the following test:

   ```
   library(multicore) # make svy fast!
   ri.ny <- subset(ipums, statefips_num %in% c(36, 44))
   ri.ny.design <- svydesign(id=~serial, weights=~perwt, strata=~strata, data=ri.ny)
   svyby(~incwage, ~strata, ri.ny.design, svymean, data=ri.ny, na.rm=TRUE, multicore=TRUE)

   ri <- subset(ri.ny, statefips_num==44)
   ri.design <- svydesign(id=~serial, weights=~perwt, strata=~strata, data=ri)
   ri.mean <- svymean(~incwage, ri.design, data=ri, na.rm=TRUE)

   ny <- subset(ri.ny, statefips_num==36)
   ny.design <- svydesign(id=~serial, weights=~perwt, strata=~strata, data=ny)
   ny.mean <- svymean(~incwage, ny.design, data=ny, na.rm=TRUE, multicore=TRUE)
   ```

   And found the means to be the same, which seems like a reasonable test.

   So: in theory, provided I can split up the calculation by either using `plyr` or `sql`, the results should still be fine.
3. See 2.
4. Throwing a lot of memory at `Stata` definitely helps, but now I'm running into annoying formatting issues. I seem to be able to perform most of the calculation I want (much quicker and with more stability as well) but I can't figure out how to get it into the form I want. Will probably ask a separate question on this. I think the short version here is that for big survey data, `Stata` is much better out of the box.
5. In many ways yes. Trying to do analysis with data this big is not something I should have taken on lightly, and I'm far from figuring it out even now. I was using the `svydesign` function correctly, but I didn't really know what's going on. I have a (very slightly) better grasp now, and it's heartening to know I was generally correct about how to solve the problem. @Gavin's general suggestion of trying out small data with external results to compare to is invaluable, something I should have started ages ago. Many thanks to both @Gavin and @Martin.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, R uses 32-bit indexes for vectors so they can contain no more than 2^31-1 entries and you are trying to create something with 2^40. There is talk of introducing 64-bit indexes but that will be some way off before appearing in R. Vectors have the stated hard limit and that is it as far as base R is concerned.

I am unfamiliar with the details of what you are doing to offer any further advice on the other parts of your Q.

Why do you want to work with the full data set? Wouldn't a smaller sample that can fit in to the restrictions R places on you be just as useful? You could use SQL to store all the data and query it from R to return a random subset of more appropriate size.

Comment: I'm not necessarily making a 2^40 size vector, I just chose much bigger number than 2^31 in the hopes that I could get around that problem. I'm not sure how big the vector is actually, I will try to find out.

Comment: The reason I want to work with the full dataset is I'm worried about how the `survey` package works, and the extent to which subsetting the data will skew my results. I don't know the details of [`svydesign`](http://faculty.washington.edu/tlumley/survey/example-design.html) objects created with probability weighting, and whether creating such an object requires the whole dataset initially, after which I can subset down. If I can't create the design object correctly though, then I can't use `R` for this at all.

Comment: @Griffith the point is the `nbins` vector **is** longer than 2^31-1 and so there would be no point trying to compute the rest of the code as R can't handle.

Comment: @Griffith I think you have this all backwards. If you don't know how something works, you use a small, well studied, dataset that you can check the results of in other software or textbook worked examples. You could for example take a sample from the whole data set, do the analysis, then take a smaller sampler for the sample you just took and redo the analyses comparing the results. That would allow you to proceed without analysing the whole data set and help you get a handle on whether you need all the data or not.

Comment: thanks very much. Did as you suggested and it looks like `syvdesign` works even on subsetted data, which is a big win. So now I need to figure out how to split it apart to perform the calculations I need (I'll probably ask a separate question on that, thanks).

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked some time ago, I'd like to point that my answer here uses the version 3.3 of the `survey` package.

If you check the code of `svydesign,` you can see that the function that causes all the problem is within a check step that looks whether you should set the `nest` parameter to TRUE or not. This step can be disabled setting the option `check.strata=FALSE`.

Of course, you shouldn't disable a check step unless you know what you are doing. In this case, you should be able to decide yourself whether you need to set the `nest` option to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. `nest` should be set to TRUE when the same PSU (cluster) id is recycled in different strata.

Concretely for the IPUMS dataset, since you are using the `serial` variable for cluster identification and `serial` is unique for each household in a given sample, you may want to set `nest` to `FALSE`.

So, your survey design line would be:

```
ipums.design <- svydesign(id=~serial, strata=~strata, data=ipums, weights=perwt, check.strata=FALSE, nest=FALSE)
```

**Extra advice:** even after circumventing this problem you will find that the code is pretty slow unless you remap strata to a range from 1 to `length(unique(ipums$strata))`:

```
ipums$strata <- match(ipums$strata,unique(ipums$strata))
```

Comment: underrated answer!